# Google Sheets - Conditional Formatting is overriding background color

Tags: google-sheets

I have a conditional format to color the background of even rows. I have another conditional format that changes the color of the text for duplicate cells, but this is removing the background color of even rows. If I switch the hierarchy of these formats, then I lose the text colouring but get back the coloured rows.

Not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no direct way to do this in Google Sheets. But, there's good workaround.

Make the **third Conditional formatting rule** with your formula, checking both conditions:

```
=and(iseven(row($A1)),countif($A1:$A,$A1)>1)
```

and set it's hierarchy to the top.

Comment: It works, thanks! There really should be an "inherit" option for the styling.